# Schema for Phone Numbers: treating Mobile as special

Tags: sql, database-schema

I'm developing a database which includes contact information.  PhoneNumbers are stored in a separate table from Person because you never know how many phone numbers a person might have.

However, the app will also deal with SMS and thus needs frequent, easy access to each Person's sms-enabled PhoneNumber (if they have one).

Should the text-enabled mobile number simply be stored separately from all other PhoneNumbers as an extra field in the Person table?  Is there some normalized way of expressing the special nature of the Mobile PhoneNumber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a bit field on the phone numbers table to indicate whether a phone number can accept SMS messages or not.

This would be a simple true/false record that is attached to the phone number and complies with normalization rules.